# CSS Overlapping shadows

Tags: html, css, z-index

https://codepen.io/gitdix/pen/NWjbZZQ

Hello

I have three `div` elements with rounded corners, both have a shadow. the shadows are overlapping. I can't fiddle out to get both shadows behind all solids `div`s and `z-index` didnt help me actually :/

How can i fix that?

thanks in advance

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
```

Comment: First of all, please put a [mre] of your issue _directly_ into the question; do not just dump the code necessary to reproduce the problem onto an external platform.

Comment: What's the expected behavior and what's the behavior you experience? The way I understand your question, the code works as it should...

Comment: @FZs "*get both shadows behind all solids divs*" -> thats the expected behavior. To answer what is the experienced behavior just click "Run code snippet" in the stack snippet.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blog.dudak.me/2014/css-shadows-under-adjacent-elements/) would help?

Comment: @dixone Here is the working solution, but I can not post it as biberman closed the question with his solution which is not working. I have already flagged this to be moderated
https://codepen.io/gitdix/pen/NWjbZZQ

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev it is reopened, but the shadows are still overlapping in your example

Comment: @MaxiGui just posted the wrong link
https://codepen.io/FalloWingS/pen/PombMaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the shadow with `:after` pseudo-element and the content in a normal `div`.
By doing it this way, I could apply `z-index` to each elements and make sure that the main content stays over the sahdow

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  position:relative; /* ADDED */
}
/* ADDED */
.box:after{
 content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  z-index:-1;
}
/* ADDED */
.box > div{
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```